# How to reply to editor's comment such as 'Such a revised paper may be refereed and there would be no guarantee of acceptance'? Is it necessary?

Tags: publications, phd, journals

I am preparing a detailed explanation of how I have dealt with all of the reviewers' and Editor's comments for a manuscript. The editor's comments are as follows:

> I regret I am unable to accept your paper for publication in XXX, at
>   least in its present form. I should, however, be prepared to consider
>   for publication a substantially revised version that takes into
>   account the suggestions of the referees. Such a revised paper may be
>   refereed and there would be no guarantee of acceptance. The three
>   referees agree that you have obtained useful results. They raise a
>   number of issues you should be able to solve relatively easily.

Is it necessary to reply to editor's comment like this? How to reply to editor's comment such as'Such a revised paper may be refereed and there would be no guarantee of acceptance'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it necessary to reply to editor's comment like this?

No. This is just making sure that you understand that revising the paper does not guarantee acceptance.

You may wish to write an introductory paragraph for the editor before you address the specific reviewer comments. Here, you may wish to thank the editor for acknowledging that the reviewers consider your results to be useful, summarise the main improvements, and conclude that you feel the manuscript is substantially better for the reviewer suggestions.

Comment: Thanks ! I found at the end of editor's letter, he point out that  ' When you revise your paper, you should prepare a detailed explanation of how you have dealt with all of the reviewers' and Editor's comments.' Is it necesary to reply to editor's comment such as 'The three referees agree that you have obtained useful results. They raise a number of issues you should be able to solve relatively easily.'

Comment: At least some of this text will be automatically generated. If the editor has added their own comments on the manuscript itself, then you should certainly respond. Other comments are at your discretion, but comments like in my example above remind the editor that they thought your work wasn't too bad, and hopefully sets the tone for their eventual decision.

Comment: This. All of that text is boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

In my role as an editor, I get fully prepared template, which I only edit, if  necessary (e.g. if there are certain aspects of the reviews that I really want to point to the author). So, you don't need to reply to a robot, in a sense. But, appropriate response to this would be a polite thankyou to the editor and the reviewers.